# Differentiate browser close event and logout

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

1) I need the following requirement to be satisfied:
Client's request(Long running process) should wait till the server is serving the request.

**Current solution:**
Client initiates the request followed by ping request every 5 sec to check the request status and 
with that also maintains the session.

2) If the client moves to other tab in the application and comes back, The client should still show the process status and server should continue working on the request.

3) If the client closes the browser or logs out, the server should stop the process.

PS : Need the functionality for all the browsers after IE-9,Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin a cat, but this is how I would accomplish it.

1, assign unique identifier to the request (You most likely have done this as you're requesting the ready state every few seconds).

Set a member of their session data to the unique ID.

Set all your pages to load the JS needed to continually check the process, but the JS should NOT use any identifier.

In the script that parses the ajax request, have it check the session for the unique identifier, and update an internal system (file or database) with the time of the last request and the unique identifier.
and push back details if there are details to be pushed.

In another system(like a cron system) or within the process itself(if in a loop for example) have it  check the same database or file system that gets updated with the timestamp for the unique identifier and the last timestamp. If the timestamp is too old, lets say 15 seconds (remember page load times may delay the 5 second interval), then kill the process if cron'd, or suicide the process if within the process script itself.

Logout will kill the session data, thus making the updating of the table/file impossible(and a check should be there for this) and that will make it so that in the next few seconds from logout, the process stops.

Comment: I liked the concept of maintaining the Ids and timer in file or DB. Is there any other way wherein, we don't need to add JS everywhere?

Comment: You could extend the timeout, but what you really need is a state of activity that the backend system can read. if you eliminate javascript entirely, then you would have to set the timeout to something like 2-3 minutes and reset it on every page navigation. This is also hoping the person doesn't just sit on the page for 10 minutes, watching the progress of the process. if the progress is not actively being updated through a continual check(like continuous ajax) then this may be the most viable option.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to find a reliable solution for logout. window.onbeforeunload will not allow you to communicate with the server (you can only prompt the user using only the built-in dialog, and that's pretty much it). Perhaps, instead of finding a solution on capturing logout/abandon, add some logic to the server's process to wait for those pings (maybe allow 30 seconds of no-comm before abandoning); that way you're not wasting server's cycles that much and you still have the monitoring working as before.